# Is it okay to run a mercury vapor lamp of lower wattage (100/150/175W) on a 400W MHL/MVL ballast? Also can a 60Hz ballast be used on 50Hz?

Tags: frequency, watts, ballast

I have this RAB BMHH400PSQ metal halide pulse start ballast 400W, M135/M155 MULTI TAP 120-277V. Since the MVL are being phased out it has become quite difficult to get a ballast for one of these and the prices are like $30- $40 easily, but still okay.

My question is can I use this 400W ballast with the 100/150/175W mercury lamps that I have? Is it like the lamp would draw only the required wattage from the ballast,or is it like the ballast would pump 400 watts into the bulb and go boom?

Also this ballast is for 60Hz. If I were to run it (240V/277V wiring) on a European 230V 50Hz supply will it damage the ballast or lamp?

Update: Picture with specs added.

[image: Ballast]

Comment: No. the trigger voltage and temperature rise from sustained voltage after ionization may be quite different. So the power and voltage trigger characteristics must match the bulb.

Comment: Although similar,  there are some important differences between mercury vapour, metal halide and HPS lamps.

Comment: The ballasts must be rated for the same current. For example after HV trigger, one bulb might arc at 100V*4A and the other at 67V*6A yet both are 400W  ( not real numbers just hypothetical)  Starting current to raise terminal temperatures are also critical in each bulb.

Comment: Frequent starting also will adversely affect lamp life, as well over wattage operation, so slightly less power ballast and few cycles extend Halide lamp life. Check Philips for supplier ballasts.

Comment: The timing of the starter stopper is carefully designed to compensate for extremes of temperature and to
allow for the lamp to adequately cool so that they can be started normally.  Ballasts must have smart restart after outage to allow cooling or adapt start time by sensing current

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist the reason I asked if I can use Mercury vapor is for two reasons. First, I have seen a lot of these ballasts say it can be used with either. But on mine its says only MH aka halide. But the person who sold it to me said he removed it from a mercury lamp fixture. He just told me don't use with M59 as it will run for a month or so and burn out. Only use M135 he said. So, from what you are saying it's a bad idea to use a lamp of lower wattage.

Comment: Matching the 4 characteristics is critical for long life but any 3 "may" work. Life can be 1kh to 30kh. I cannot verify what you were told. It may work or not "so hot", or too hot.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A halide ballast must do 4 things well. So consider existing ballast specs as very important.  MH bulbs are still the best white light sources for even spectrum.

1. Providing the correct starting current.
2. Providing the correct starting voltage.
3. Providing the correct sustain current.
4. Provide the correct restart profile to a hot bulb after a power outage.

It may also be possible that the capacitor is the only thing worn out. which might be $15 similar to large microwave caps. 26uF 330Vac 0.82MOhm which can be tested by some techs.

[https://www.amazon.com/RAB-Lighting-BMHH400PSQ-Halide-Ballast/dp/B00415KW80](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00415KW80)

Comment: I've added a picture with the specifications.

Comment: It would be like matching a FET for a BJT transistor application.  Possible but someone needs to have the exact load and cct. on hand to know.  The label only shows input current and not bulb current. Considering they are on Amazon, you can confirm proper ballast PN and compare then ask the supplier about being phased out.